# Why one of my interfaces receives DHCP requests

Tags: linux, networking, centos, dhcp

I have a server with multiple interfaces. One [Eth_ext] is connected to external network and other two [eth0, eth1] are connected back-to-back to another server.

- Say eth0 is on 10.0.0.0/24 subnet
- and eth1 is on 20.0.0.0/24 subnet

For some reason the eth1 is constantly getting requests:

```
 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP
```

While eth0 does not. I can uses either subnet to connect in between two servers.

I would like to know where are those messages coming from and why only appear on eht1 and most crucially how can I stop them from being received/generated.

Both interfaces are configured identically:

```
DEVICE=eth1
NAME=eth1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPADDR=20.0.0.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
```

Comment: Because something on your network sends them out, or they get routed there. You may be able to get the physical MAC of the device and track it down.

Comment: @Lenniey I would expect the external eth to get them but why would they appear on eth1 and only eth1. There are not routes created for eth0 and eth1.

Comment: Do you have any VMs or anything on your servers?

Comment: No, nothing else is running on it yet. I am setting it up atm.

Comment: Using tcpdump find out the mac address of these broadcast packets then turn off the device with an interface that has that mac address.